# Installing node packages / dependencies using npm on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-server-2008, package, npm

I downloaded the node js binaries for windows, it contains all the cygwin dependencies, etc.

So I can cd to the C:\Program Files (x86)\node\bin folder and run 'shell' then 'node npm install' and the command works.

What exactly do I point it to? I tried pointing it to the packages .tar.gz / .zip or the extracted folder as per the documentation but I receive several errors,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\node\bin>node npm install andris9-Nodemailer-10eb182
npm ERR! tar -cvf - <file list elided> execvp(): No such file or directory
npm ERR! tar -cvf - <file list elided>
npm ERR! Failed creating the tarball.

npm not ok
```

How is this most simply done in Windows? Read many tutorials but they all vary in explanation and none seem to work.

If there is a simpler way to just reference dependencies from my main .js file that would help too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine that you should be able to just download the source and put the libraries in manually.

From NPM:

> locally —- This installs your package in the current working directory. Node modules go in ./node_modules, executables go in ./node_modules/.bin/, and man pages aren’t installed at all.

I'm pretty sure that would work.. i think.