# Building syntaxhightlighter with nodejs in windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows-7, syntaxhighlighter

I need to build Syntaxhighlighter from here: https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter

I have read these:
https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html
[Getting started with NODE.JS in windows x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345710/getting-started-with-node-js-in-windows-x86?rq=1)
[Get started with Node.js in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431784/get-started-with-node-js-in-windows)
[Installing node packages / dependencies using npm on Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678915/installing-node-packages-dependencies-using-npm-on-windows-server-2008)

It seems that installing Nodejs from here http://nodejs.org/download/ should be enough.

Step 3 in the syntaxhighlighter Building instructions says:

> 3.Then ./node_modules/.bin/bower install to download dependencies

I have this path on my machine:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin

and I can see a bower.json in the syntaxhighlighter zip file.

I have googled how to download dependencies for windows, but I cant find anything.
There is a lot of info here:
 [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)
but I think this is not for windows env.
Can you assist?

EDIT:
Ok, seems to work now.
Installed Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe and restarted.
Step 8 ok now.
Step 9 gives "grunt not recognized".
Tried

> npm install -g grunt-cli

from here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/774
Now I have a pkg folder

Thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install NodeJs for Windows per instructions
2. Install [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win), select option to Add Git to your path.
3. Open a new command prompt in Windows. Ideally, open as an Administrator. Do not reuse existing command prompts. The path will only be set in a new command prompt properly.
4. Download the code for the highlighter or use git to clone
5. If you got the zip file, unzip it
6. From the command prompt, change the active directory to be the folder of the code you cloned or unzipped
7. Type `npm install -g grunt-cli`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each of the following...
8. Type `npm install -g bower`
9. Type `npm install`
10. Type `bower install`
11. Type `grunt build`

Done.

Comment: Thank you sir,
On step 9 I get "bower ENOGIT  git is not installed or not in the path.". Cannot find how to resolve this.

Comment: And step 8 gives
  npm WARN package.json uglify-js@2.2.5 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field

Comment: Sorry -- I'd forgotten git was a requirement, and messed up on the `grunt-cli` npm package name.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install git package in this way:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

It's working fine!

Comment: This isn't an answer for Windows.